# Convert LaTeX to HTML

Tags: html, latex

There is an old webpage written in HTML and CSS that is distributed on a CD to be read locally on the user's computer even with no internet access. Up to now, all equations have been added to the page as pictures. This now needs to be changed. All equations are to be added in LaTeX.

Is there a way to do this without linking to a CDN?

Thanks for any help, Ruby

Comment: If I understand properly your problem, you do not want a LaTeX to HTML converter, but a png (or jpg, gif, or whatever) to LaTeX converter. You really should [edit] your question to update the question title. And while there are many LaTeX to HTML converion tools, AFAIK, there is no tool that can be given a picture of a math expression and that can reliably deduce the LaTeX code for the formula.

Comment: No, @AlainMerigot, I am _not_ looking for a picture to HTML converter. 

All equations are being converted to LaTex by myself as this is the only reliable way and the equations are needed in some other place, too (which is not part of my question).

As I said before, I need something to convert LaTex to HTML without the need to install additional software or linking to a CDN.

Answer (score 1):

May be mathscribe(jqmath) helps you- https://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html